# Apply EF migrations in GitHub workflow

Tags: asp.net-core, github-actions, ef-core-3.0

I have a GitHub repository for my Asp Net Core project with EF Core 3.0. I added the following workflow to run each time on updating the `develop` branch

```
name: Develop Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.0.102-servicing-014397
    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release
    - name: Test with dotnet
      run: dotnet test --configuration Release
    - name: Update database
      run: dotnet ef database update --c DataContext --p MyProj --s MyProjFactory
```

The last line returns with an error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I apply the latest migrations to the target database using this workflow?

Comment: In 3.0 dotnet ef command is not installed by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: I've executed this command `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` but still get errors running database updated

Comment: What's the error? Do you have permission to install global? You should probably use local tool, see docs.

Comment: @jcemoller, the error said `Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '3.1.0') was successfully installed.
Run "dotnet tool restore" to make the "dotnet-ef" command available.` so, I added 'dotnet tool restore' and it helped

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also had to add commands to install EF tool and to restore all tools to make my workflow work correctly:

> ```
> - name: Update database
>   run: |
>     dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
>     dotnet tool restore
>     dotnet ef database update -c DataContext -p MyProj -s MyProjFactory
>   env:
>     ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
> ```

Comment: In my case it complains that the db connection string, which in app service I obtain from configuration, is missing. How do you provide the connection string to github actions?

Comment: My website is hosted on AWS and I am using (this action)[https://github.com/abhilash1in/aws-secrets-manager-action] to get access to secrets and have them as environment variables. I am sure you can find something similar for Azure

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked and going to Windows Server is not a solution for me. Note: I am using a self-hosted Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS runner with practically nothing installed.  I got it working like this.

First, make sure Dotnet is installed.

```
    - name: Setup Dotnet
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
```

Next, create a step to install the dotnet-ef tool using a new manifest. This solves the issue of not being able to install the tools if they're already installed globally.

```
    - name: Install dotnet-ef tools
      run: |
        dotnet new tool-manifest
        dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
```

Finally, run your migrations using the **dotnet tool run dotnet-ef** command

```
     - name: Create DB Migration Script
       run: |
        cd src/project
        dotnet tool run dotnet-ef migrations script -i -v -o "${{ github.workspace }}/dbscripts/Migrations.sql"
```

I do hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run your workflow in a windows [environment](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources), i.e. using `windows-latest` rather than `ubuntu-latest`. You can see the software installed on windows [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners#windows-server-2019).

For `Windows Server 2019`, it says:

> PATH: contains location of dotnet.exe

There is no mention of `dotnet` being on the PATH for the Linux environments